# About drain time in UVM

Tags: system-verilog, uvm

I am new to UVM. I have a question about the concept of "drain time". I am wondering how can the "drain time" be useful in a real uvm test environment?
It will be better to show with an example.

Thanks~!

Answer (score 1):

Drain time is the period between the last objection to ending a phase, and the actual time the phase is terminated. It usually represents the time it takes for your last set of stimulus (a sequence) to propagate through your design and its output to be captured by a monitor.

You can find examples here: http://blog.verificationgentleman.com/2014/04/uvm-drain-time-old-fashioned-way.html

Comment: In a real project, why we need to use setting drain time to ensure there is no more transactions going on? Why don't we just wait the transactions to be finished, what is supposed to do next?

Comment: The use of *drain time* is very design dependent and is just one of many mechanisms used to help end a test.